# What is the market share between Canon and Nikon in the US?

Tags: canon, nikon

I can't seem to find reliable data indicating the market share of DSLRs here in the US between Canon and Nikon. Most that I've talked to have always argued that Nikon and Canon are pretty evenly split. But to be honest, in the past year or so, I almost feel that Canon have a 75% share from my own observations. Where can I find this data?

Comment: I have read that between the two of them, Nikon and Canon have a 95% market share of DSLRs $2000 and up. However, I'm not sure if this really answers your question.

Comment: @EvanPak - No. They have 100% of that market. No one else makes a DSLR above $2K. Even if you add other full-frame in there, which means the Sony A99V and RX1, I doubt it would account for more than 1% of that number.

Comment: @Itai, I may have been mistaken. This statistic could have been digital cameras over $2000, which would add Hasselblad, Phase one and Leica. I could also be mis-remembering something else.

Answer (score 3):

It is difficult to pin down camera sales for the US only, as Canon and Nikon have many divisions (printers, imaging, instruments) and don't seem to report financial results at a very detailed level).

According to their own data (worldwide):

Canon (fiscal year ending 31-Dec 2012)

- sold 8.2 million interchangeable lens cameras (Canon reference, page 3)
- sold 18.3 million compact cameras (page 4)

Nikon (fiscal year ending 31-Mar 2013)

- sold 7.0 million interchangeable lens cameras (Nikon reference, page 7)
- sold 17.1 million compact cameras (page 7)

So based on that one year they are pretty even. Nikon had a poor 2011 due to flooding in Thailand, so it's possible that 2012 was better than average due to deferred sales.

Sources:

- [Canon, Inc. Q4 2012 Earnings Call Transcript](http://www.morningstar.com/earnings/40173751-canon-inc-adr-q1-2012.aspx?pindex=4)
- [Nikon Fiscal Year 2013 Results](http://www.nikon.com/about/ir/ir_library/result/pdf/2013/13_all_e.pdf)

See also:

- [Canon financial statements](http://www.canon.com/ir/annual/)
- [Nikon financial results](http://www.nikon.com/about/ir/ir_library/result/#y2013)

Comment: Worldwide numbers are what we have but geographic distribution is extremely skewed. Some brands with very little popularity in North America are extremely popular elsewhere. For compact cameras this is even more skewed.

Comment: Regarding Itai comment that is a good observation, I can give a good example in Argentina. Here, even when Nikon doesn't give you an official warranty if you don't buy it in an official and local store, most people have Nikon. But Canon for example, give you an official warranty even if you buy it through ebay from Zimbabwe :D That's very strange for me. Behaviors, marketing...